# Recover data from formatted harddrive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, grub, data-recovery

I had a dual boot machine with Windows 8 and Deepin linux on it. Last week I removed WIndows 8 and installed windows 8.1.

After installing Windows 8.1 grub was removed. I followed [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) to restore grub.

After repairing the machine restarted but for some reason after restarting in the middle of booting it shutdown.

Now the machine is not booting into any of the OS installed - it shows error message like "no boot device found please insert boot device and press any key".

I tried booting a live CD and it appears I have lost all my partitions and data.

I think it got formatted.

Is there any way to recover the lost partion data. If yes, how?

What all the requisites for that? is it possible to recover data into the same harddrive or do I need an external harddrive to store recover the data?

I Googled and got many tools which are available, but none have proper documentation on how to recover. My problem is I am not able to access any of the OS, so how can I to use the mentioned tool?

There are some bootable data recovery tools, but I dont know how to use them.

Comment: Try Easeus data recovery, this tool is good at recover from hard drive or lost partition.

Comment: we should install it right ? but in my case i am not able to boot into os then how shall i use this software.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted one of my partitions and i recovered it using  Active@ Partition Recovery Tool, Its not free*. It is like Linux OS you can live boot to it and recover files and partition. its really good.

here is a video btw : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tl5XgWJ3xK8
Title : "Recovery of accidentally deleted partition with Active@ Partition Recovery"

The video shows how to recover using the .exe file, not how to recover using the live OS tool.

*youtube can help ;)